# Multer is not populating req.body and req.file

Tags: node.js, express, multer, keystone, form-processing

I am using Multer to parse a multipart form in a keystone environment and and not able to access the req.body and req.file data inside my route controller

routes/index.js

```
var keystone = require('keystone'),
    middleware = require('./middleware');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//multi-part form parser for FTP api
var multer = require('multer');
var storage = multer.memoryStorage();
var upload = multer({storage: storage});

exports = module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '10mb'}));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '10mb', extended: true}));
    app.post('/upload_api', upload.single('formFile'), routes.api.uploadFTP);
};
```

routes/api/uploadFTP.js

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var ftpMod = require('ftp');
var fs = require('fs');

exports = module.exports = function(req, res) {
    console.log("req.body is ");
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log("req.file is ");
    console.log(req.file);
    res.send("console.log() outputted to screen");
}
```

public/test-upload.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form name="sampleForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload_api" method="post">
            <p>Method</p>
            <input type="text" name="method"><br>
            <p>Options</p>
            <input type="text" name="options"><br>
            <p>File</p>
            <input type="file" name="formFile"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Click to Send">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The response i receive from nodejs is

```
>req.body is 
{}
req.file is 
undefined
```

I am expecting `req.body` to contain {method: "sometext"}
and `req.file` to be populated

Answer (score 0):

You can not get values in either `req.body` or `req.file`. Replace youe uploadFTP.js with below given code.

```
var multer = require('multer');
var path = require('path');

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, <<path where you want to store your files>>);
  },
  filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, path.basename(Date.now() + '_' + file.originalname));
  },
});
var maxSize = 1024 * 1024;
var upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: function(req, file, callback) {
    var ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
    if(ext !== '.gif' && ext !== '.jpeg') {
      return callback(res.status(202).end();, null);
    }
    callback(null, true);
  },
  limits: {fileSize: maxSize},
}).single('image');

exports = module.exports = function (req, res) {

  upload(req, res, function(err) {
    console.log(storage.diskStorage);
    if(err) {
      return res.status(201).end();
    }
    //Do stuff here
    res.status(200).end();
  });
}
```

Replace below line in index.js

```
app.post('/upload_api', upload.single('formFile'), routes.api.uploadFTP);
```

with

```
app.post('/upload_api', routes.api.uploadFTP);
```

Comment: Im confused about removing the `upload.single('formFile')` middleware from index.js

I am also confused by the function upload(req, res, function(err){}): in the uploadFTP.js file.

Where did upload.single() go?

This all seems very different from the documentation provided by express/multer

Comment: The example code from the documentation is

    var multer = require('multer');
    var storage = multer.memoryStorage();
    var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
    app.post('/profile', upload.array(), function (req, res, next) {
        // req.body contains the text fields 
    });

Comment: This is the working code from my application. You can keep Middleware if you wish. I have called upload.Single() from actual method

Comment: Thank you for the example. It is not working. The file is not being placed where I expect it, and I still dont have any access to req.file or req.body.method